# Load List<string> from .txt

Tags: c#

```
var wordsToHighlight = new List<string>() { "sign ID1:", "user:", "autohotkey", "bloody" };

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(richTextBox1.Text))
    foreach (var word in wordsToHighlight)
        int index = 0;

        while (index != -1)
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            index = richTextBox1.Find(word, index + word.Length - 1, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
```

I am currently using this code to search and highlight words in a richtextbox.
In the same folder as the program, Can you use a .txt file of words to replace `{ "The", "is", "what", "story" }` and use those words from the .txt file to search with.

Example: (The words in the .txt file are the following)

```
Line 1 = The
Line 2 = is
Line 3 = what
Line 4 = story
```

Comment: you don't even have curly braces after `foreach`. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: I am opening a log file into a richtextbox and I am searching + highlighting keywords from a list which is { "The", "is", "what", "story" }. Although, I want to change those keywords in a .txt file and scan the log file with those keywords.  So I want the .txt file to replace the { "The", "is", "what", "story" }. In doing so, I will not have to rebuild the program everytime I need to change the keywords. I am stuck like Chuck.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `File.ReadAllLines()` to read the lines of your file into a `string[]`. This may then be converted to a `List<string>`, but you needn't even bother - arrays are `IEnumerable`, so you can do

```
foreach (var word in File.ReadAllLines(path_to_wordlist))
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am getting 2 errors. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0136 A local or parameter named 'word' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter
Error CS0103 The name 'wordsToHighlight' does not exist in the current context

Comment: These error messages are as close to plain english as compiler messages are likely to get. Check the complete code you currently have to make sure that "word" and "wordsToHighlight" are declared exactly once.